# Linux script to run systemctl --user commands with a specific user

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I'm creating a bash script where I try to install a program as a user service but I'm unable to run `systemctl --user` commands within the script.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

(...)

useradd -M -g user -d "$3" user 

(...)

[I create the unit file and move it to ~/.config/systemd/user/]


runuser -l user -c "systemctl --user list-units"

su user << 'EOF'

export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u user)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/run/user/$(id -u user)/bus

systemctl --user daemon-reload

EOF

exit 0
```

So, both the runuser and the here document result in an error.

The runuser outputs:

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

The here document outputs:

> Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused

I've been looking around for a solution but haven't yet found anything specific for this particular case.

Has anyone faced something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels weird answering my own question but I managed to find a solution by doing the following:

```
(...)
mkdir -p "/home/user/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/"
chown user:user -R "/home/user/.config/"

loginctl enable-linger user

su user << 'EOF'

export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u user)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/run/user/$(id -u user)/bus

systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable my-service.service
systemctl --user start my-service.service

EOF
(...)
```

Enabling linger was enough for daemon-reload but after that, the enable was failing because the folder `/home/user/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/` didn't exist yet.

One strange thing is that even if linger is enabled, and I can see the `/lib/systemd/systemd --user` process running for that user, when I do `su user` and login to its shell, I still cannot run `systemctl --user` because it outputs:

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
> Only after setting the environment variables again inside that su session I can run the `systemctl --user` commands again.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this error means that the D-Bus session-bus socket doesn't exist, or that it exists but is a "stale" socket with no process listening on it anymore. For systemctl, it also means the private "direct channel to systemd" socket doesn't exist either (as systemctl would have automatically used that as fallback).

Altogether, it means that the user's `systemd --user` service manager is **not running at all**, so it is pointless to 'daemon-reload' at this time – nothing is currently loaded to begin with.

In general, `su` and `runuser` aren't meant to start the user service manager; they don't register a full "login session" via pam_systemd. You can only use them to access an already-running user service manager.

(But even if it were running, it's rarely useful to use 'daemon-reload' after installing new units; it's only needed to make systemd notice changes to existing units that it has already loaded since startup.)

You should probably install the service unit to `/etc/systemd/user` so that it'd be automatically available to all users without the need for your shell script.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for the explanation, now it makes sense. In that case, how do I start and stop a service from `/etc/systemd/user` ? Can I just simply use `systemctl` as one typically does or should I include `--user` as well?

Btw, I should add that I have to run this script as root. The whole picture is that I'm installing 2 tomcats as a service for a specific user so the application within one tomcat can user systemctl stop and start on the other tomcat service.

Comment: Should you really use `--user` services for webapps, though? (I assume you're planning to use "linger" mode to keep them running?)

Comment: Yes, I intend to "linger it". I'm going for this route to avoid having the "NOPASSWD" directive in the sudoers.d. The idea is to have this unprivileged user starting and stopping that one tomcat service. Is using a webapp with --user a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

[Systemd 248](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/28795f2c138203fb700fc394f0937708af886116/NEWS#LL2820C10-L2820C10) introduced a `-M` option that allows you to connect to another user's daemon more easily.

Also as @u1686_grawity mentioned, you probably want to install such global unit files into `/etc/systemd/user` instead. If you want to enable these units by default (which to my understanding is what you want), you can also do so for all users. So in this case you can do this:

```bash
sudo cp your-unit.service /etc/systemd/user/
# I don't think `multi-user.target` exists for user daemons
# You can verify this with `systemctl --user list-unit-files -t target`
# You should use `default.target` instead
sudo systemctl --global enable your-unit.service


for USER in user0 user1 user2; do
  # these two may not be necessary
  sudo systemctl -M "$USER@" --user daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl -M "$USER@" --user enable your-unit.service

  sudo systemctl -M "$USER@" --user start your-unit.service
done
```